# Detecting whether a permission can be requested or is permanently denied

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

**Situation**
One of my fragments accesses the camera. So of course i need to check the permission in my activity first, before i redirect to it. If the user denies the permission the Activity finishes and redirects him to the previous Activity he was in.
Additionally I would like to show a different fragment when the Activity starts and detects that the permission was permanently denied. (The little checkbox "Never ask again" on the android permission dialog)

**Problem**
I could not find a proper way of detecting, wether the permission was only denied once or if the "Never ask again" checkbox was checked last time and denied the permission permanently.
Keep in mind that I don't want to know that in the onRequestPermissionsResult callback. I need to know in the onCreate of my Activity if the permission currently is granted, denied or permanently denied.

**What I tried**
`ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` seems to detect wether the permission has been denied in the past or not. It also returns true if it has been denied only once instead of permanently.

`PermissionChecker#checkPermission()` didn't seem to notice any difference between permanently and only once denied permission state.

**Question**
Is there any way of detecting, wether a permission is denied but can still be requested or if it is permanently denied?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there any way of detecting, whether a permission is denied but can
>   still be requested or if it is permanently denied?

Unfortunately there is no official API available to detect if permission is permanently denied when user selects "**Never ask again**"

There is one work around which uses `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`. Create a SharedPreference with default value `false` and store value returned by `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` in it. Before updating the value, check if the value set was `true`. If it was `true` then don't update it.

Whenever you want to check for permission, get the value from `SharedPreference` and current value returned by `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`. If  `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` returns `false` but value from `SharedPreference` is `true`, you can deduce that `Never ask again` was selected by user.

You can refer to my [blog](https://medium.com/@begalesagar/method-to-detect-if-user-has-selected-dont-ask-again-while-requesting-for-permission-921b95ded536) where I have described this approach.

Comment: How "safe" is it to assume, that this is always works? Does shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale not have a chance to return true straight away with the first request?

Comment: @Basti Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#explain)  `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale ` returns true only if the user has previously denied the request. This should be reliable enough

Comment: Great, thanks. Sad that android doesn't offer API for that. Still gonna stress test this solution tho ofc :D

Comment: @Basti Yeah, that's sad. It would be great if you could let me know if you find some issues during your stress test

Comment: Couldn't find any complications.

Comment: When I tested this on android 11 it had major problems. If the user went into the settings and selected "Ask Every Time" this approach still returns that as a "Permanently Denied"

Comment: For anyone wanting a concrete example of how to use shared preferences to detect when the user has denied a permission permanently, see [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/android-runtime-permission-experiments/tree/master/app2) small, minimal app that I have put together. For further discussion, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826849/1071320).

Answer (score 8):

`shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` returns true or false based on the user preference in previous permission request.

If user just denied permission(not forever) `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` will return `true`.
If denied permission for ever, then returns `false`.
And the trick is that, even the user allowed permission then then `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` will return `false`.

So we can combine both the conditions to get the never ask again chosen or not.

So if user not allowed permission and `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` returns `false` then it means user opt for never ask again for the permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dexter library, A library that makes handling android permissions easier. I solved the problem this way:

```
private void checkUserPermission() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
            //check if all permission are granted
            if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                initSocket();
            } else {
                List<PermissionDeniedResponse> responses = report.getDeniedPermissionResponses();
                StringBuilder permissionsDenied = new StringBuilder("Permissions denied: ");
                for (PermissionDeniedResponse response : responses) {
                    permissionsDenied.append(response.getPermissionName()).append(" ") ;
                }
                showInfoMessageToast(permissionsDenied.toString());
            }

            if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                //permission is permanently denied navigate to user setting
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Need Permissions")
                        .setMessage("This application need to use some permissions, " +
                                "you can grant them in the application settings.")
                        .setPositiveButton("GOTO SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                dialog.show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
            token.continuePermissionRequest();
        }
    })
            .onSameThread()
            .check();

}
```

that is after creating an import this way

```
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
```

Tweaking that to what you want to achieve, should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the permission by,

```
if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, false)){}
```

Normally I check the permission using following,

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

   if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(TrackActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TrackActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
       } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, false)) {

       } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TrackActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
       }
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, true);
            editor.apply();
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

This library works well: https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher

Also this medium article is useful: [Detecting wether a permission can be requested or is permanently denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639292/detecting-wether-a-permission-can-be-requested-or-is-permanently-denied)

Comment: this link to the medium article is wrong

Answer (score -3):

To detect that the user is permanently denied the permission or not we don't need any extra logic just use it

```
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(UserEditProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                // not permanently denied 
            }
            else {
               // permanently denied 
            }
```

that's it.

Comment: the problem is that if we havent asked yet at all it will also return permanently denied ;-)